# Calculate surrounding rectangles after cutting out rectangles

Tags: geometry

Assuming we cut out one or more, potentially overlapping, rectangular holes in a rectangle - how do we calculate one possible set of rectangles that cover the rest of the main rectangle? See example photo with 2 cut-outs and 7 new rectangles covering the non-cut-out area.

I don't even know what to search for. Pretty sure it is a known problem, but I don't know what it is referenced by :-)

One solution could be to cut horizontal slices matching all upper and lower limits of the holes. Or split it all into small rectangles in a grid that is made up from all the corners of the holes - and maybe then merge some of those.

Edit: rectangles are represented as floating point values for all four corners, it is not a grid based system - the grid squares on the drawing is only there to ease drawing by hand.

[image: Example cut-out]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one systematic way to create such a set of rectangles, assuming there are no other restrictions or requirements involved:

1. Number the remaining grid squares, where 1 is the top left, 2 is the next one to the right, etc. going right and down. (Depending on how you are actually implementing this, you might also just imagine the numbers, instead of literally writing them down.)
2. Locate the lowest-numbered square which is not already either cut out or rectangled off. This is the top left corner of a new rectangle; let's call it $R$.
3. Go as far to the right as you can, until you hit a hole / another rectangle / the edge of the paper. This is the top right corner of rectangle $R$.
4. Go as far down as you can, until the edge along the bottom hits a hole / another rectangle / the edge of the paper. This is the bottom right corner of rectangle $R$.
5. Return to step 2, and repeat until the entire paper has been rectangled off.

Applying this process to the example in your picture generates the following partition:

[image: Rectangle partition]

Another possible systematic procedure, designed to hopefully give rectangles that are a bit more squareish, at the cost of probably ending up more complicated:

1. Extend the edges of all the holes outwards, until they either hit the edge of the paper or the edge of another hole. These extended edges constitute a set of line segments. In your example, there will be 24 such segments.
2. Delete the longest horizontal/vertical segment which has an equally wide/tall rectangle on either side of it. (Decide ties arbitrarily.)
3. Return to step 2, and repeat until no more segments can be validly deleted.

Result:

[image: Rectangle partition 2]

(Note: another equally valid application of this procedure would have the rectangle below the bottom hole extend 3 more squares to the left & right; it depends on whether you delete horizontal segments first as I did vs. vertical segments first.)

Last, but also least... here is another, technically equally valid procedure:

1. Just cut the paper along all the gridlines.

Applying this last process to the example in your picture, you get 225 very small rectangles (in particular, squares... but a square is a type of rectangle, after all).

This last result probably isn't what you're looking for, realistically. ;) It's my tongue-in-cheek way of suggesting you consider whether you may want to put additional restrictions on the problem - such as a requirement that the paper be partitioned into the smallest possible # of rectangles, for example.

EDIT: Just realized I missed a row between the holes. Oh well, you still get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Name a partition out of rectangles with the minimal number of rectangles possible "#-minimal".

Another procedure: Elongate all cuts with dotted lines until the outer boundary. Exception: Boundaries of rectangles are not dotted.

In this way, one gets a partition into rectangles. I conjecture (but don't have the time to prove) that this is a finer partition of all of the "#-minimal" partitions. Then, you could get all of the #-minimal partitions by backtracking: Melt two rectangles (if existing), which share a common line for its whole length, together.

Note that in each melting step, the finite number of rectangles is lowered and there are only finitely many cuts to melt. Therefore, the algorithm finishes.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (not optimal) would be to make iterative horizontal and vertical cuts at the boundaries of the rectangles (see figure).

[image: Possible configuration for two overlapping rectangles.]

Answer (score 0):

Based on ideas from @indnwkybrd, here is what I suggest: extend all corners upwards (from top corners) and downwards (from lower corners) until they either hit the edge or another hole. If starting corner is inside another hole, ignore it.

It may not be an optimal solution, but it should be fairly easy to implement.

[image: Cutting up in rectangles]